# Filter dictionary by item boolean - API Python

Tags: python, api

I'm new to Python and trying to filter a dictionary by an item. Steps to reproduce:

```
import requests

# Get a list of planets and convert from Json.
space = requests.get("https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies/")
arr = space.json()

# Select only planets.
{k:v for (k,v) in arr.items() if isPlanet == True}
```

Error:

```
NameError: global name 'isPlanet' is not defined
```

I know `isPlanet` is correct, I have verified with another language. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you're looking for something like this.

```py
[v for v in arr['bodies'] if (v['isPlanet'] == True)]
```

`arr['bodies']` will return you a list of all bodies

`v['isPlanet']` allows you to access that key in a dictionary

There's no point doing `arr.items()`, since `arr` has only one key (`bodies`)

`{}` is replaced with `[]`, so we're getting a list instead of a dictionary as output

Answer (score 1):

The JSON response you get is a dict with just one key:value. key is `bodies` and value is a list of dicts.

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

# Get request with JSON response.
response = requests.get("https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies/")
data = response.json()

# Make a list with the planets.
planets = [item for item in data['bodies'] if item.get("isPlanet")]
pprint(planets)
```

output

```
[{'alternativeName': 'A899 OF - 1943 XB',
  'aphelion': 445410000,
  'aroundPlanet': None,
  'axialTilt': 3,
  'density': 2.161,
  'dimension': '',
  'discoveredBy': 'Giuseppe Piazzi',
  'discoveryDate': '01/01/1801',
  'eccentricity': 0.07582,
  'englishName': '1 Ceres',
  'equaRadius': 487.0,
  'escape': 510.0,
  'flattening': 0.9619,
  'gravity': 0.28,
  'id': 'ceres',
  'inclination': 10.593,
  'isPlanet': True,
  'mass': {'massExponent': 20, 'massValue': 9.393},
  'meanRadius': 476.2,
  'moons': None,
  'name': '(1) Cérès',
  'perihelion': 382620000,
  'polarRadius': 455.0,
  'rel': 'https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies/ceres',
  'semimajorAxis': 413690250,
  'sideralOrbit': 1681.63,
  'sideralRotation': 9.07,
  'vol': {'volExponent': 9, 'volValue': 4.21}},
 {'alternativeName': '2003 UB313',
  'aphelion': 14594512904,
  'aroundPlanet': None,
  'axialTilt': 0,
  'density': 2.52,
  'dimension': '',
  'discoveredBy': 'Michael E. Brown, Chadwick Trujillo, David L. Rabinowitz',
  'discoveryDate': '05/01/2005',
  'eccentricity': 0.44068,
  'englishName': '136199 Eris',
  'equaRadius': 0.0,
  'escape': 1380.0,
  'flattening': 0.0,
  'gravity': 0.82,
  'id': 'eris',
  'inclination': 44.0445,
  'isPlanet': True,
  'mass': {'massExponent': 22, 'massValue': 1.66},
  'meanRadius': 1163.0,
  'moons': [{'moon': 'Dysnomie',
             'rel': 'https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies/dysnomie'}],
  'name': '(136199) Éris',
  'perihelion': 5765732799,
  'polarRadius': 0.0,
  'rel': 'https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies/eris',
  'semimajorAxis': 10180122852,
  'sideralOrbit': 203830.0,
  'sideralRotation': 25.92,
  'vol': {'volExponent': 9, 'volValue': 6.59}},

... rest of list elements skipped for brevity ...
]
```

in addition - the API provide you with the option to filter data you get based on certain criteria (i.e. you can filter the data you get in response), however thee is a bug with `filter[]=isPlanet,eq,true` (see https://github.com/systeme-solaire/api-rest/issues/3).

```
import requests

# Get a list of planets and convert from Json.
params = {'filter[]':'isPlanet,neq,false'}

response = requests.get("https://api.le-systeme-solaire.net/rest/bodies", params=params)
data = response.json()
planets = data.get('bodies')
# print just len of planets list
print(len(planets))
```